# How to re-level factor in ordinal logistic regression model in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am currently working on an ordinal logistic regression model with R. The output coefficients are using the same reference level. I am wondering how can I change the reference level? Be more specific, see the example below. I do not want to use real data, so I simulated one. Both a and T are from 1 to 5

```
polr(formula = T ~ a, data = d, Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
      Value Std. Error  t value
a2  0.18823     0.5734  0.32825
a3  0.14747     0.5287  0.27895
a4 -0.50157     0.5766 -0.86985
a5  0.02843     0.5448  0.05219
```

The coefficient of "a" use reference level 1, a2, a3, a4, and a5 basically compare level 2,3,4,5 with reference level 1. My question is how can I relevel it so that the output will give a3|2, a4|3, a5|4(i.e. the beta3-beta2,beta4-beta3) automatically? I have search around and didn't find similar question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A very very quick and dirty is to rename your variables. a1 is your baseline because alphabetically, a1 < a2, a3, a4, a5.

Comment: i suggest you improve your searching skills: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force R to use a specified factor level as reference in a regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression)

Comment: I think `MASS::contr.sdif()` does the kind of contrasts you want. So `contrasts(d$a) = MASS::contr.sdif(5)` before running your `polr` command.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: the contrasts outlined in the question don't just involve setting a different reference level for treatment contrasts, that's not a dupe.

Comment: @Marius Thank you so much, your code works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `contr.sdif` function from the MASS package: from `?contr.sdif`,

> The contrast coefficients are chosen so that the coded
>        coefficients in a one-way layout are the differences between the
>        means of the second and first levels, the third and second levels,
>        and so on.  This makes most sense for ordered factors, but does
>        not assume that the levels are equally spaced.

So:

```
library(MASS)
contrasts(d$a) <- contr.sdif(5) # set contrasts: from @Marius in comments
polr(formula = T ~ a, data = d, Hess = TRUE)
```

According to the documentation for `?polr`, it should be possible to add the argument `contrasts=list(a=contr.sdif)` instead of setting the contrasts on the variable itself; however, this seems to give an error (an analogous setup works fine for `lm`).  This *looks* like a bug in `polr` to me, but that's somewhat hard to believe since this a venerable and well-tested part of R ... Where possible (maybe not in this case) I prefer the `contrasts` argument in the formula because it's a bit more explicit/visible when reading the code, but tastes differ.

Comment: I tried with the argument inside the formula, but it gives me the following error.     invalid type (list) for variable '(contrasts)'