# Linear regression - baseline referencing madlib

Tags: postgresql, machine-learning, linear-regression, madlib

I am using MadLibs linear regression train function to analyze `coef`. While doing so I came across baseline referencing for independent variables.

Something similar to `relevel()` in R. [How to force R to use a specified factor level as reference in a regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression)

Does MadLib provide any feature which could be used to achieve this?

Or if Madlib implements/run it  internally with [linregr_train](http://madlib.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__linreg.html) ?

I couldn't find the parameter where I could specify a baseline for independent variables on Madlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By baseline reference, do you mean the reference for dummy encoding of a categorical independent variable? If yes, then MADlib expects that the data has been encoded before passing it to the regression methods. See [Encoding Categorical Variables](http://madlib.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__encode__categorical.html) for the procedure to dummy encode. The `value_to_drop` parameter provides the functionality for user-defined reference level.