# Changing the reference alllele used in logistic regression (glm) in R

Tags: r

I am using the glm function in R to ascertain the risk of individual alleles to a disease; it is a case-control study. When I run the glm function, R automatically takes the allele with the lowest digit or in alphabetical order as the reference allele. I need to change this according to the each gene and the most neutral allele (i.e. the allele which has an even distribution among the cases and controls). How do I do this. The code I use currently is;

```
modelA <- (glm(trait ~ sex + A, data=Almon, family = binomial(link = 'logit')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `relevel()` -- or if you're using the `forcats` library, `fct_relevel()` -- to change the levels so that the reference comes first.

Much more here: [How to force R to use a specified factor level as reference in a regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression)