# How to get the reference level of a factor column?

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

I know you can use `relevel` to set a value as the reference level of a factor.

I want to do the opposite: given a factor column, how can I retrieve the reference value?

I guess the most trivial way would be to run a regression with `lm` and see which value is missing from the estimated coefficients.

Is there a method/function for this?

---

I feel silly asking this, but searching how to retrieve the reference level of a factor results in tons of questions asking how to relevel a factor (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression)). I couldn't find anything on how to do the opposite, so I apologize in advance in case this is a duplicate!

Comment: The reference is the first level of the factor, so you can just use `levels(x)[1]`.

Comment: That's great. Thanks! Does this hold after releveling a column? If so, do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, please post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lotus is right.

> The reference is the first level of the factor, so you can just use
> `levels(x)[1]`.